# Angular – loosing reference to `this` when passing function as parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am building an Angular application, and I have two services, call them `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`. `ServiceB` has two methods that `ServiceA` uses in the same way, something like this:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceA {
    constructor(private _b: ServiceB) {}

    doFoo(input: Whatever): void {
        this._b.foo(input)
            .pipe(...);
            .subscribe(...);
    }

    doBar(input: Whatever): void {
        this._b.bar(input)
            .pipe(...); // exact same pipe as above
            .subscribe(...); // exact same subscribe as above
    }
}
```

Since I have duplicate logic, I tried to do this in `ServiceA`:

```
performFooBarAction(input: Whatever, fooBarFn: (input: Whatever) => Observable<void>): void {
    fooBarFn(input).pipe(...).subscribe(...);
}
```

And call it from both methods like this:

```
doFoo(input: Whatever): void {
    this.performFooBarAction(input. this._b.foo);
}
```

But, if I do it like that I get an error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined

So, I tried to add `console.log(this)` to `serviceB.foo()`, and – lo and behold – `this` is `undefined` when I pass the function as an argument. It worked before my little refactor.

Any idea if this is unavoidable, or is it me who's doing it wrong?

Comment: use ```.bind(this)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by invoking the `call` method and passing it the reference to `ServiceB` as context, like so:

```
performFooBarAction(input: Whatever, fooBarFn: (input: Whatever) => Observable<void>): void {
    fooBarFn.call(this._b, input).pipe(...).subscribe(...);
}
```

But if someone can tell me if there is a better way, I'd be thankful.

---

**[EDIT] - Another solution**

Since I discovered I actually won't have the same parameter list for `foo()` and `bar()`, I came up with another way, which doesn't require context passing, and works in both cases - I simply passed the `Observable`s that come from `_b.foo()` and `_b.bar()` like this:

```
handleFooBarAction(input$: Observable<void>): void {
  input$.pipe(...).subscribe(...);
}
```

Which I can now call like this:

```
doFoo(input: Whatever): void {
    this.handleFooBar(this._b.foo(input));
}

doBar(): void { // no params
    this.handleFooBar(this._b.bar()); // no params
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceA {
    constructor(private _b: ServiceB) {}

    doFoo(input: Whatever): void {
        this._b.foo(input)
            .pipe(...);
            .subscribe(...);
    }

    doBar(input: Whatever): void {
        this._b.bar(input)
            .pipe(...); // exact same pipe as above
            .subscribe(...); // exact same subscribe as above
    }

    callMethodByName(input: Whatever, funcName: string) {
        this._b[funcName](input).pipe().subscribe();
    }

}
```

A working sample is attachted below:

```js
class Testing {

logName(name) {
    console.log(`Name is ${name}`);
}

logAge(age) {
    console.log(`Age is ${age}`);
}

print(funcName, data) {
   this[funcName](data);
}
}

const tes = new Testing();
tes.print('logName', 'Apoorva Chikara');
tes.print('logAge', 29)
```

Comment: I'll try it out, but there is just one thing I don't like - by passing string, I now have to worry about renaming. If I rename a function on `ServiceB`, I need to reflect that in that string as well. Thanks for the answer, anyway!

Comment: Yes, If you change the function name you need to change the string name too, your case does require to pass the function by reference. There will always be one change involved if you change the function name.

Answer (score 1):

bind context when passing function as an argument:

```
 doFoo(input: Whatever): void {
        this.performFooBarAction(input. this._b.foo.bind(this._b));
    }
```